# ogr2ogr exporting from MSSQL slow -- relatively

Tags: ogr2ogr, sql-server-spatial

So when I pull the same stored procedure on my machine in SQL Server Management, we get 600+ megabits for about 100 seconds.  Keep in mind this SQL Server has plenty of RAM, Cores, etc, and 20gig networking.  So all of the backend stuff should be nice and quick.    Everything, all of the WKT is delivered within that 100 seconds without issues.

But when I run this same stored procedure on ogr2ogr to convert to a local file, we basically get about 8-20 megabits.   During ogr2ogr we get copy/BCP as 1, so assuming it is using BCP< note that we are NOT writing to SQL just getting data.  Any thoughts on how to make this quicker?

I am saving as a shapefile, but I have tried GeoJSON as well.  Is this just a limit of the ogr2ogr program?

Comment: It may be a limitation of the MSSQL driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mssqlspatial.html rather than in ogr2ogr. You can make a test by saving the data first from MSSQL into GeoPackage and then making a copy of the GeoPackage with ogr2ogr. If the latter is fast then the slowness is in the MSSQL driver. Adding `--debug` into your ogr2ogr command may give some information about what is the bottleneck.

Comment: I've always found MSSQL slow on output and input

Comment: If this is the case, what other methods can I use to output WKT data from SQL?  Or is there another/better driver I should be using?

Comment: Any updates on this?